# How can I get Log4j2 to log to my log file, I've tried everything I can think of, could it be a configuration issue in linux?

Tags: java, linux, logging, log4j2

My log4j2.xml is exactly the same as the one I've written for another similar server - which works perfectly well. The only differences are the file/server names and paths.
Log4j1 worked fine too, it's just log4j2 that's causing problems. I'm starting to think I might have missed something in the linux config at this point. 
Things I've tried:

- Including log4j2.xml in the root directory of the project
- Including log4j2.xml in the `main.resources` folder of my project
- Using  `-Dlog4j.configurationFile="PATH"` when running the jar (via systemd)
- Verified the folder/log file are owned by the server user and server group
- Verified that the server has `rw` permissions for the file/folder
- Verified that the server user is a member of the correct group

Also, when I run `systemctl status -l` on the server, the resulting output shows the log data as I expect to see it in the `firmwareserver.log` file.
My other server uses the log4j2.xml file from `main.resources` in the project without any issues.

**EDIT:** I should add, I'm developing this in eclipse on a windows machine, and when I run it there the log file saves as expected, even using the linux path it still works.

**EDIT 2:** I found the following error when I ran the jar file directly instead of as a systemd service:

```
2016-03-11 14:06:39,601 ERROR Unable to locate appender RollingFile for logger
```

Here's my Log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" monitorInterval="30">
        <Properties>
                <Property name="windows-log-path">C:/log4j/</Property>
                <Property name="linux-log-path">/var/log/wsfirmwareserver</Property>
        </Properties>
        <Appenders>
                <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${linux-log-path}/firmwareserver.log"
                        filePattern="${linux-log-path}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/firmwareserver-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
                        <PatternLayout>
                        <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+1} [%-5p] [%t] - %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5MB" />
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30" />
                </RollingFile>
                <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] - %m%n" />
                </Console>
                <SMTP name="SMTPAppender"
                    smtpProtocol="smtps"
                    smtpPort="465"
                    subject="LOC SERVER:Error"
                    to="me@myjob.com, me@otheremail.com"
                    from="notifications@myjob.com"
                    smtpHost="smtp.gmail.com"
                    smtpUsername="notifications@myjob.com"
                    smtpPassword="thepassword"
                    bufferSize="512"> 

                        <PatternLayout>
                                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}{GMT+1} [%-5p] [%t] - %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                </SMTP>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
                <Logger name="root" level="info" additivity="false">
                        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="info" />
                </Logger>

                <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
                        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug"/>
                        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
                        <AppenderRef ref="SMTPAppender" level="error"/>
                </Root>
        </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Anybody got any suggestions? 
Ideally I'd like to have the config file located in the same folder as the server jar, but at this point I just want it to log to the file properly.

Comment: Are there any errors from it?

Comment: not that I can see. I'm not sure where that log file systemd uses is. let me check that out.

Comment: nope. can't see any errors in the service logs either

Comment: You have gone through the obvious like file permissions on all the way along the path `/var/log/wsfirmwareserver`? Which version of log4j are you using? If you create the timestamped directory, `/var/log/wsfirmwareserver/2016-03` for example, beforehand and don't trust log4j to create it, does this change anything?

Comment: I'm using `log4j 2,2` via maven, with `log4j-api` and `log4j-core`. I haven't created the time-stamped directory, I didn't have to do that with the other server. I created the `firmwareserver.log` file though, as I had issues in the past when that wasn't created beforehand. I haven't checked the permissions all the way along the path, my other servers are fine, I never had to do that for them, and they are the same path except for the folder name at the end. But I'll take a look at which groups the various servers belong to.

Comment: The owner/group permissions for the other folders in the path are all `root root`, with the permissions `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: OK, after disabling the service and running the jar directly I came across the following error, which looks like the problem: `2016-03-11 14:06:39,601 ERROR Unable to locate appender RollingFile for logger`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the log4j2.xml file itself. 
I haven't located it, but replacing it with a copy from another server fixed the issue.